# Autocomplete Field with jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, sql, ajax, autocomplete

I am trying to populate multiple fields with jQuery from user input in one form but I'm not getting any result in JSON. Can anyone spot what the problem is?

```
$('#countryname_1').autocomplete({
    source: function( request, response ) {
    $.ajax({
        url : 'search.php',
        dataType: "json",
        data: {
           name_startsWith: request.term,
           type: 'country_table',
           row_num : 1
        },
         success: function( data ) {
             response( $.map( data, function( item ) {
                var code = item.split("|");
                return {
                    label: code[0],
                    value: code[0],
                    data : item
                }
            }));
        }
    });
},
autoFocus: true,
minLength: 0,
select: function( event, ui ) {
    var names = ui.item.data.split("|");
    $('#country_no_1').val(names[1]);
    $('#phone_code_1').val(names[2]);
    $('#country_code_1').val(names[3]);
}
});
```

The PHP I'm using to query the database

```
require ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/config/dbconnect.php');

if(isset($_POST['type']) == 'country_table'){
$result = $db->prepare("SELECT firstname, department FROM users where      firstname LIKE '".strtoupper($_POST['name_startsWith'])."%'");
$data = array();
while ($row->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){{
    $name = $row['firstname'].'|'.$row['department'].'|'.$row_num;
    array_push($data, $name);
}
echo json_encode($data);
}
}
```

Nothing appears in the form and Chrome shows that no data is being passed back

Comment: Extra `}` in php comes from what?

Comment: You're not actually executing your query. [prepare()](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php) returns a PDOStatement object (if successful) that you then use to call [execute()](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php). Also, you should really be using bound parameters.